# Accessors (Getter) & Mutators (Setter) On a Pivot Table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that connects users to workspaces. On the pivot table, I also have a column for role, which defines the users role for that workspace. Can I provide Accessor (Getter) & Mutator (Setter) methods on the role inside the pivot table? I have been trying to look all over, but details on pivot tables in eloquent are pretty sparse.

I am not sure if I have to setup a custom pivot model? If I do, an example would be awesome as the documentation on pivot models is very basic.

Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to do it manually. Here is what I have: http://laravel.io/bin/RE2ze

Answer (score 10):

If all you need to do is access additional fields on the pivot table, you just need to use the `withPivot()` method on the relationship definition:

```
class User extends Model {
    public function workspaces() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Workspace')->withPivot('role');
    }
}

class Workspace extends Model {
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User')->withPivot('role');
    }
}
```

Now your role field will be available on the pivot table:

```
$user = User::first();

// get data
foreach($user->workspaces as $workspace) {
    var_dump($workspace->pivot->role);
}

// set data
$workspaceId = $user->workspaces->first()->id;
$user->workspaces()->updateExistingPivot($workspaceId, ['role' => 'new role value']);
```

---

If you really need to create accessors/mutators for your pivot table, you will need to create a custom pivot table class. I have not done this before, so I don't know if this will actually work, but it looks like you would do this:

Create a new pivot class that contains your accessors/mutators. This class should extend the default Pivot class. This new class is the class that is going to get instantiated when User or Workspace creates a Pivot model instance.

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;
class UserWorkspacePivot extends Pivot {
    getRoleAttribute() {
        ...
    }
    setRoleAttribute() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, update your User and Workspace models to create this new pivot table class, instead of the default one. This is done by overriding the `newPivot()` method provided by the Model class. You want to override this method so that you create an instance of your new UserWorkspacePivot class, instead of the default Pivot class.

```
class User extends Model {
    // normal many-to-many relationship to workspaces
    public function workspaces() {
        // don't forget to add in additional fields using withPivot()
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Workspace')->withPivot('role');
    }

    // method override to instantiate custom pivot class
    public function newPivot(Model $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists) {
        return new UserWorkspacePivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
    }
}

class Workspace extends Model {
    // normal many-to-many relationship to users
    public function users() {
        // don't forget to add in additional fields using withPivot()
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User')->withPivot('role');
    }

    // method override to instantiate custom pivot class
    public function newPivot(Model $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists) {
        return new UserWorkspacePivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
    }
}
```

Comment: I very much appreciate your detailed response, but unfortunately, this does not work. The 'getRoleAttribute' and 'setRoleAttribute' never get applied.

Comment: @ATLChris I just tried this is a test environment and it looks like it is working.  Can you post your current code, as well as what you're trying to do, what you're expecting to happen, what is actually happening, and any errors you're getting?

Comment: @ATLChris this solution is working. I have solved this issue using this approach. For more detail you can read the article [Laravel – Custom pivot model in Eloquent](http://softonsofa.com/laravel-custom-pivot-model-in-eloquent/)

Comment: @patricus This will not work for mutators when calling `$user->workspaces()->attach($workspace, ['role' => 'some role']);` or `sync` in the same manner. This could cause some big problems later when someone tries to call this. My answer tries to fix this aspect of your answer but it is a lengthy and ugly process. I +1ed your answer because there is some really good info but you should add that it doesn't mutate the data passed in `attach` and `sync`.

Comment: @hhsadiq Your article has a slight error.  When calling the custom pivot, its only expecting 1 argument, which is $attributes.  Thanks for the write up though, it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to use `Accessors` and `Mutators` on the Pivot table (I'm using Laravel 5.8)

You must use `using()` on your `belongsToMany` relationships, for example:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model {
    public function workspaces() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Workspace')->using('App\UserWorkspace');
    }
}
```

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Workspace extends Model {
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->using('App\UserWorkspace');
    }
}
```

So, use your Pivot model:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class UserWorkspace extends Pivot {
    public function getRoleAttribute() {
        // your code to getter here

    }
    public function setRoleAttribute($value) {
        // your code to setter here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult question. The solutions I can think of are smelly and may cause some problems later on.

I am going to extend on Patricus's answer to make it work.

I was going to comment on Patricus's answer but there is simply too much to explain. To make his solution work with `attach` and `sync` we must do some ugly things.

**The Problem**

First let's identify the problem with his solution. His getters and setters do work but the belongsToMany relationship doesn't use the Pivot model when running `sync`, `attach`, or `detach`. This means every time we call one of these with the `$attributes` parameter the non-mutated data will be put into the database column.

```
// This will skip the mutator on our extended Pivot class
$user->workspaces()->attach($workspace, ['role' => 'new role value']);
```

We *could* just try to remember that every time we call one of these we can't use the second parameter to attach the mutated data and just call `updateExistingPivot` with the data that must be mutated. So an `attach` would be what Patricus stated:

```
$user->workspaces()->attach($workspace);
$user->workspaces()->updateExistingPivot($workspaceId, ['role' => 'new role value']);
```

and we could never use the correct way of passing the pivot attributes as the `attach` methods second parameter shown in the first example. This will result in more database statements and code rot because you must always remember not to do the normal way. You could run into serious problems later on if you assume every developer, or even yourself, will just know not to use the `attach` method with the second parameter as it was intended.

**The Solution** (untested and imperfect)

To be able to call `attach` with the mutator on the pivot columns you must do some crazy extending. I haven't tested this but it may get you on the right path if you feel like giving it a try. We must first create our own relationship class that extends `BelongsToMany` and implements our custom `attach` method:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class UserWorkspaceBelongsToMany extends BelongsToMany {
    public function attach($id, array $attributes = [], $touch = true)
    {
        $role = $attributes['role'];
        unset($attributes['role']);
        parent::attach($id, $attributes, $touch);
        $this->updateExistingPivot($id, ['role' => $role], $touch);
    }
    // You will need sync here too
}
```

Now we have to make each `Model::belongsToMany` use our new `UserWorkspaceBelongsToMany` class instead of the normal `BelongsToMany`. We do this by mocking the `belongsToMany` in our User and Workspace class:

```
// put this in the User and Workspace Class
public function userWorkspaceBelongsToMany($related, $table = null, $foreignKey = null, $otherKey = null, $relation = null)
{
    if (is_null($relation)) {
        $relation = $this->getBelongsToManyCaller();
    }

    $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();

    $instance = new $related;

    $otherKey = $otherKey ?: $instance->getForeignKey();

    if (is_null($table)) {
        $table = $this->joiningTable($related);
    }

    $query = $instance->newQuery();

    return new UserWorkspaceBelongsToMany($query, $this, $table, $foreignKey, $otherKey, $relation);
}
```

As you can see, we are still calling the database more but we don't have to worry about someone calling `attach` with the pivot attributes and them not getting mutated.

Now use that inside your models instead of the normal belongsToMany:

```
class User extends Model {
    public function workspaces() {
        return $this->userWorkspaceBelongsToMany('App\Models\Workspace')->withPivot('role');
    }
}

class Workspace extends Model {
    public function users() {
        return $this->userWorkspaceBelongsToMany('App\Models\User')->withPivot('role');
    }
}
```

Comment: You're really hardcoding on the `UserWorkspaceBelongsToMany` class.

Answer (score 0):

Its impossible to use setters, will not affect pivot table... make the change in the controller instead.