# How to add mutators in custom pivot class laravel5

Tags: php, laravel

I have `many to many` relation between Order and Product. Pivot table `order_product` has additional columns: `price`, `quantity`.
I have custom pivot class:

```
class OrderProduct extends Pivot
{
    protected $attributes = ['price', 'quantity'];

    public function getPriceAttribute($value)
    {
        return number_format($value, 2);
    }

    public function setPriceAttribute($value)
    {
        $price = $value - ($value * 0.1);
        $this->attributes['price'] = $price;
    }    
}

class Product extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class, 'order_product')->using('App\Models\OrderProduct')->withPivot('price','quantity');
    }
}
```

Accessor works but mutator doesn't.
How to make mutator `setPriceAttribute` working with `sync()`, `attach()`?

`$value` is correct in `setPriceAttribute`, but modifications are not applied in DB?

Comment: here is a link that will explain this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921787/accessors-getter-mutators-setter-on-a-pivot-table-in-laravel

Answer (score 2):

Implement the mutators and accessors in relevant Models.

```
class Product extends Model
{




  public function getPriceAttribute($value)
   {
    return number_format($value, 2);
   }

  public function setPriceAttribute($value)
  {
    $price = $value - ($value * 0.1);
    $this->attributes['price'] = $price;
  } 
  public function orders()
   {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class, 'order_product')->using('App\Models\OrderProduct')->withPivot('price','quantity');
   }
}
```

Hope this helps